# Cannot push github cloned Xcode project in the repo

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github

I cloned the project materials from github as advised and then worked on it as shown in the tutorial I'm following. To push the finished project in my own repo -

1. first I removed the .git from the folder using command line .
2. But while I try to push those project folders on my git repo, in github desktop it shows the file is empty but in reality it has all the necessary files inside it.

In another scenario, initially I pushed those projects using command line, they got pushed in the repo but was greyed out and couldn't open the folders inside the repo.

[image]

Comment: Why did you remove the .git file? I cloned the project from GitHub and it a works fine.

Comment: @TheAppMentor because before removing .git file it was giving me error showing the link of the main repository while I tried to push it in my own repository. After removing the .git file, I followed the normal procedures for github push and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I discussed this problem with one senior of my uni. He suggested to create a new folder and moving my mentioned problematic project folders to it. It worked! But couldn't figure out the reason behind this issue though.